# How to get Windows 10 to update Microsoft Office 2016 using Windows Update?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, windows-update, microsoft-office-2016

I have Microsoft Office 2016 installed on my PC. In the past when I was using Office 2013, Office 2013 was automatically updated through "Windows Update" under Settings. However, this is not so for Office 2016. For Office 2016, I have to update it by going to File->Account->Update follow steps in web link below. https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/44833-check-updates-office-2016-windows.html

How can I get Windows 10 to update Microsoft Office 2016 using Windows Update?

Comment: But it could be done in Office 2013. I wonder why Microsoft changed the way things were done which were better.

Answer (score 4):

There are two versions of Office installations.

There is the MSI version, and the Click-to-Run version.

If you are an Office 365 subscriber you probably have click-to-run.

MSI versions update through Windows updates as long as you have the Windows Update option selected to, "update other Microsoft products."

If you have the click-to-run version it updates independently of Windows updates. In addition, there are different update channels you can choose. Depending on your Office 365 subscription you may be in a delayed channel. If it's delayed, you won't be updated as often.

There is no reason to have to update manually. If you do, something is wrong.

Here is information to get you on the right track.

[Determining your office version - MSI or C2R.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_integration__sharepoint/2016/06/23/determining-your-office-version-msi-vs-c2r/)

[Turn ON or OFF updates for other Microsoft products.](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/44926-turn-off-windows-updates-microsoft-products-windows-10-a.html)

[Version and build numbers of update channels](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Version-and-build-numbers-of-update-channel-releases-ae942449-1fca-4484-898b-a933ea23def7)

[How to switch channels for Office 2016 ProPlus.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/odsupport/2017/05/10/how-to-switch-channels-for-office-2016-proplus/)

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get Windows 10 to update Microsoft Office 2016 using Windows Update?

It is not possible to update Office 2016 and above through Windows Update if you have a Click-to-Run Office 2016 license.  If you want that capability downgrade to Office 2013.

The Windows installer version of Office 2016 is only available as a Volume License.  Based on what you describe, the license you have, is only available as a Click-to-Run installation.

> Windows Installer technology (MSI) is used to install the volume license editions of Office, like Microsoft Office Professional Plus and Microsoft Office Standard.

[Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-installed-with-Click-to-Run-and-Windows-Installer-on-same-computer-isn-t-supported-30775ef4-fa77-4f47-98fb-c5826a6926cd)